# Python's Virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am using Virtualenv to learn Python. The author of the book I am reading wants no system wide access of Python available during learning, so we created a virtual environment via virtualenv. This is not built-in Python 3 virtual environment functionality, it is the pip virtualenv. It's an issue for me because I cannot figure out how to run a script while inside the virtualenv. Virtualenv's documentation reads that activation (or path naming) isn't required when running from within the virtual environment's directory and although I have moved my file both there and within the Scripts directory, I cannot run it while inside the virtualenv environment. Any help? I am using Python 3.6.1. The code I'm trying to run is:

```
def local():
    m=7
    print(m)

m=5
print(m)
```

I realize it's not even training wheel code, but what I'm trying to ultimately do is be able to run code from within the virtual environment to follow as the book suggests. I'm also using a fully updated Windows 10 OS.

What happens when I run the script is this:

```
(.virtualenv) c:\users\aiii> cd c:\users\aiii\desktop\learning.python\.virtualenv

(.virtualenv) c:\users\aiii\desktop\learning.python\.lpvenv>scopes1.py

'scopes1.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

(.virtualenv) c:\users\aiii\desktop\learning.python\.lpvenv>python scopes1.py
python: can't open file 'scopes1.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.

(.virtualenv) c:\users\aiii\desktop\learning.python\.lpvenv>
```

I have placed the script both directly in the learning.python folder where the environments are contained `c:\users\aiii\desktop\learning.python\.lpvenv` and inside the .lpvenv folder in the Scripts folder since that is where other scripts run from within the virtualenv pip are at `c:\users\aiii\Desktop\learning.python\.lpvenv\Scripts\`

Comment: What methods have you tried to run the script?  Did you try just `python scriptname.py`?

Comment: I would suggest you to install [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) it makes working with virtual environments much easier!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read The Tour and refer to the material from the Help Center what and how you can ask here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask Also provide your Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example by editing your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: First of all python3 has virtual environment builtin `python3 -m venv myvenv` would create a new venv named `myvenv`. You havent specified what you trying to do exactly (like what is the folder structure, where is your script and where is you venv and what commands you're trying to execute) but you've probably forgot to activate venv.

Comment: The only ways I know to run a Python script as of now is to either double-click the script wherever it's saved, or to run it from the directory it's in like any other file: `C:\path\to\file\script.py`. I enter the virtualenvironment by calling `c:\env\Scripts\activate` from within my project root. Once I have the environment prompt, I use the above example of running a Python script.

Comment: The book is not using Python's built in virtual environment functions although it did mention them. I am learning from the book, Learning Python by Packt Publishing. So anything to do with Python's built-in venv is probably (??) not applicable to virtualenv the package. My folder structure was mentioned in my previous comment, but if you would like a more specific answer, `C:\users\aiii\desktop\learning.python` is the folder in which my environments are kept and the scripts are kept one folder further in at `\lpvenv` where the environment itself is at.

Comment: @Andy, please include that information (exact steps, exact output/error) *in the question itself*; see the [edit] button. Right now, it's not clear from the question text what problem you're actually having.

Comment: I don’t use Windows enough to be sure, but I would guess that for its virtualenv functionality to work, you need to explicitly say `python script.py` instead of just `script.py`. The latter would ask Windows to run whatever program runs Python scripts, which is the global python, while the former would ask Windows to find `python` in the `%PATH%`, which the virtualenv activation would have changed to use the local virtualenv copy. This is a comment, not an answer, because any of what I said might be wrong.

Comment: If you are on the latest Windows 10, I suggest working through the bash shell.  It will probably work a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

First, install Virtualenv:

```
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
```

Then Create Virtualenv:

```
virtualenv venv #venv is name
```

For activating virtualenv.First, move to folder, In which you want to enable and run this command:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Once, Your work is done then disable virtualenv:

```
deactivate
```

Comment: My issue is not installing virtualenv, creating a virtualenv, or activating it, it's working within the environment itself. I can start a Python prompt and enter code line by line in the prompt, but I cannot run a saved Python script. Thanks. I'm also not using Linux, but Windows 10.

Comment: @andy Can you share? which script you are not able to run ? Please provide complete information related to your Os and other required source cpde.

Comment: Yes, the file is present but I see the problem now, for some reason it was appended as scopes1.py.py? Not sure when this happened but using that file extension the script does run. Thank you.